# Turning off monitor in C

Tags: c, linux

I have an algorithm that I am processing in C.  It takes a while to complete, so to save power, I want to turn off the screen.

After a quick search on Google (https://askubuntu.com/questions/62858/turn-off-monitor-using-command-line) I found I can turn off the screen using the simple commands:

```
xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
```

This works a treat,  however I would like my C code to turn off the screen automatically, as soon as it starts.

I was thinking something along the lines of `system("xset -display :0.0 dpms force off");` however, I've always been discouraged from doing this (and have had some bad experience in the past).  Is there a better way to get this done (hopefully a system call or similar)?

I am aware that a bash script may be perfectly suited to the job however, I'm looking to keep everything purely inside my program, if possible.

Comment: I have never heard using `system` is discouraged. In any case you're in danger of injection attacks where a malicious entity may want to override what `xset` refers to, causing `system` call to launch a different process than you intended. But provided you are launching as regular user (not root), this isn't any different from pretty regular system usage on Linux. A person who has access enough to alter what `xset` refers to may as well sideload a library with your process and alter a deeper-level call you'd use instead of `system`, anyway.

Comment: You may alternatively peek into the source code of `xset` to figure out what it is exactly that puts the monitor to sleep:  You can alternatively peek in xset source code: https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/app/x11-xserver-utils/blob/fed54c72d60f741fc7e90dfb420bde3274f85871/xset/xset.c

Comment: Reading deeper into your question, I say it's not within the scope of your program to control the monitor. You are right that this is best left to a script which launches your program and then puts the display to sleep. Separation of concerns comes to mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the same thing as `xset dpms force off`:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/dpms.h>
#include <err.h>
int main(void){
        Display *dpy;
        if(!(dpy = XOpenDisplay(0)))
                errx(1, "cannot open display '%s'", XDisplayName(0));
        DPMSEnable(dpy);
        DPMSForceLevel(dpy, DPMSModeOff);
        XSync(dpy, False);
}
```

compile it with `cc xdfo.c -o xdfo -lX11 -lXext`.

`xset` also sleeps 100 ms after the `DPMSEnable`, I have no idea why it does that.